# Solr case insensitve

Tags: configuration, lucene, solr, case, case-insensitive

Hallo,

I'am implementing an autocompletion feature in Solr and have one problem.

For autocompletion I am using

```
<fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I thought that the LowerCaseFilter should make the Token Case insensitiv but that ist wrong. In fact in just lowercases the Token which means that a query like "comput" would lead to "computer" while "Comput" doesn't. 
Actually I want comput and Comput to lead to Computer.

I allready tried this:

```
<fieldType name="text_auto_low" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType> 

<fieldType name="text_auto_up" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For some reason it doesn't word either. My question is why and haw can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has the Analyser class which you can use(implement) in three ways:

- **SimpleAnalyzer** : This converts all of the input to lower case.
- **StopAnalyzer** : This removes words that removes noise from your search.
- **StandardAnalyzer** : This does both the above filter processes and thus can 'clean up' your query.

Now, coming to your question, i would recommend a techinque called **ngram** that splits up your query and then searches for those phrases instead. Thus, you can still get excellent results even if there are typos.

To know how to do this, i suggest you to read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html) to get you started. It also has other great info regarding queries.
This not only will solve your problem, but will enhance your app.

Have fun :D

Comment: Hey, i found a similar post. See if it helps too : Here is the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487736/lucene-case-sensitive-insensitive-search) :)