# Lucene how to switch between case sensitive and case insensitive

Tags: java, search, lucene, full-text-search

I want to give user the option to do case case sensitive or case insensitive search.

My idea is use a case sensitive analyzer to index the data and then use sensitive or insensitive analyzer to search depending on user input.

So I created my case sensitive analyzer and here is a simple of my code:

```
public final class CaseSensitiveStandardAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {
  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName, final Reader reader) {
    final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    src.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, src);
    tok = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tok, stopwords);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok) {
      @Override
      protected void setReader(final Reader reader) throws IOException {
        src.setMaxTokenLength(CaseSensitiveStandardAnalyzer.this.maxTokenLength);
        super.setReader(reader);
      }
    };
  }
```

For indexing I used this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new CaseSensitiveStandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46,analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir,config);
indexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

For searching I used:

```
Analyzer analyzer;
if(caseSentive)
    analyzer = new CaseSensitiveStandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
else 
    analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46,"content", analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
//Search 
TopDocs results  = indexSearcher.search(query,10000);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
```

When I tired this, the sensitive case worked, but the insensitive case didn't.

After more researching, I found that using a case-sensitive analyzer with a lower-care query will not work. Case-sensitive analyzer indexed work with case-sensitive query and case-insensitive analyzer indexed work with case-insensitive query, can anyone confirm this?

It seems to me the only reliable way to search both case-sensitive and case-insensitive is to index twice, one for each case, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me the only reliable way to search both case-sensitive and case-insensitive is to index twice, one for each case, is this correct?

That would be a possible solution, but there are more optimal solutions for that use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490441/867816

This might help, too: http://www.hascode.com/2014/07/lucene-by-example-specifying-analyzers-on-a-per-field-basis-and-writing-a-custom-analyzertokenizer/